# Grails spring security issue with url redirection coming from a desktop app

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've a problem with [spring security core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)

I've a excel spreadsheet and one cell has a link to a resource of my webapp (eg. http://localhost:8080/myapp/item/1)

If I click the link, it opens the browser (the same where I'm already logged in) and instead of going to the url that I clicked, it sends me to home (default target url)...

I've changed the bean authenticationProcessingFilter and I log what is happening in the doFilter and this is what I get

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/item/1
E5E79669EBC938953AC6DCA4F1D38D56 <- this is the session id
false <- just printing if I'm logged in
http://localhost:8080/myapp/login/auth
1446A2704FC61E6304F0AC95F8BDAF22 <- this is the session id, and now is different
true <- just printing if I'm logged in
http://localhost:8080/myapp/home
1446A2704FC61E6304F0AC95F8BDAF22 <- this is the session id
true <- just printing if I'm logged in
```

I don't know why it changes the session id, this all happens in the override doFilter of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

```
public class MyAuthFilter extends RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter {

   @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest r2 = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        println r2.getSession().getId();
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```

How can I redirect to the url that I clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason of the session id changed was because Session Fixation, thanks to [smakela](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=258585) in the [grails forum](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-spring-security-issue-with-url-redirection-coming-from-a-desktop-app-td4168969.html#a4169229)

> Reason for changing the session id is to prevent "Session Fixation".
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation
>
> http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/19%20Session%20Fixation%20Prevention.html

Ok I coud fix it....

instead of going to myapp/item/1

I go to an unsecure url like myapp/item/load/1

and I've page that say something like "Loading item" and then by javascript, redirect to myapp/item/1

and it worked!

thanks